# Java Heap Space out of memory on HBase Table scan

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, hbase

In my application, I am scanning a table in HBase to fetch the data to be shown on UI. Data is huge in amount and code is giving the below error. Provided Server Configuration is: server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m

```
"Failure in caller transaction.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
```

Code:

```
HTable table = null;
        try {
            Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hbaseServer);
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", hbasePort);
            FilterList list = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
            table = new HTable(config, "tableName");
            SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(filterName),
                    Bytes.toBytes(filterName), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes (String.valueOf(filterValue))));
            list.addFilter(filter);
            Scan scan = new Scan();
            scan.setFilter(list);
            scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

If I add the below filter to reduce the count of records, data is getting rendered without error:

```
scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(100));
```

But if I extract the heap dump using Memory Analyzer Tool in Eclipse, heap dump size is created of the same size irrespective of the count of records fetched from HBase. I have also added the below code to avoid caching but again the results are not varying.

```
            scan.setCaching(0);
            scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
```

Does that mean that the heap dump generated does not depend upon the amount of data to be fetched? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: An OOME may also be thrown due to an obviously unsatisfiable allocation request, which won't show up in a heap dump. You should check the server's error log if it contains a stacktrace or run it under a debugger with an exception breakpoint for OOMEs.